# Db2: How to reorder columns during import or load?

Tags: import, db2, txt

For eg:
Table has the 3 columns:

```
Name varchar(10),        
ID   int,    
Place Varchar(10)
```

File has ID,name and place in a different order that as the table above:

```
1|Ram  |Ayodhya              
2|Rahul|Srilanka
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the column list in the Db2 [IMPORT command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html) as part of the INSERT clause.

```
IMPORT .... INSERT INTO yourTable(ID, NAME, PLACE)
```

The same reordering of columns can be performed for the [LOAD command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html), too.

Comment: Yes, sure. You asked for IMPORT. Both LOAD, IMPORT and INGEST share a common syntax. If that addresses your question, please mark answered and upvote (up arrow)

Comment: how can i do this if i have to use replace command instead of insert

Comment: If you followed the link to the syntax, you should have seen that both INSERT and REPLACE have the same "column list" clause. Have you tried it?